# Loading pickled (dill) file containing dictionary of functions

Tags: python, pickle, dill

This is a follow-up to a question I previously asked: [Loading functions in pickle file that uses class wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996760/python-loading-functions-in-pickle-file-that-uses-class-wrapper), where I wanted to pickle a dictionary of function [under class wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883491/pickling-scipy-interp1d-spline), but the class wrapper module couldn't load.

I have since solved this using `dill` instead of `pickle`:

```
func_dict = lowess_record()

wanted = ['func_dict', 'Interp1dPicklable', 'PolyValPicklable', 'dill', '__builtins__', 'wanted']

for name in globals().keys():
    if name not in wanted:
        del globals()[name]

del globals().wanted

with open('./func_dict.p', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(globals(), f)
```

I removed some unnecessary variables (involved in creating func_dict from data) from `globals()`, they weren't needed as I only wanted to work with func_dict.

Now when I load the pickled file using:

```
func_dict_loaded = dill.load(open("./func_dict.p", "rb"))
```

I get:

```
<In> func_dict_loaded.keys()

<Out> ['_dh', '__', 'dill', '_15', '__builtin__', '_i32', '_30', '_16', '_i15', quit', '_34', '_i11', '_i9', '_i8', '_i7', '_i6', '_i5', '_i4', '_i3', '_i2', _i1', '__package__', 'exit', 'get_ipython', '_i', '_i29', '_i26', '_i17', _i24', _i14', '_i22', '__doc__', '_i20', '_i16', '_i21', '_18', '_11', '_i34', __builtins__', '_ih', '_i28', 'sys', '_20', '_i27', '__name__', '___', '_i33', _', '_sh', '_i25', '_29', '_32', '_22', 'func_dict_loaded', '_i23', '_i13', _i12', '_iii', '_i10', '_13', '_12', '_ii', 'In', '_i31', '_i30', '_i19', _i18', _i35', '_oh', 'Out']
```

With no way to access the dictionary of functions! What do I need to do to get the intended output?

Comment: Great post for a new user!

Comment: Thanks @иσαнcяişтiпσ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it, here's how:

when dumping the function dictionary, instead of:

```
dill.dump(globals(), f)
```

I have used:

```
dill.settings['recurse'] = True

with open('./Data/function_dict.p', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump([dill, interp1d, Interp1dPicklable, PolyValPicklable, func_dict], f)
f.close()
```

The first line is a tip I found [here](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/126)

Then, when I load the `.p` file I call:

```
dill.settings['recurse'] = True

func_dict_loaded = dill.load(open("./Data/function_dict.p", "rb"))
```

(Not sure if the first line is needed there but it doesn't seem to do any harm.)

Then:

```
func_dict_loaded[-1]
```

Returns func_dict (note order of list when dumping).

I can then use

```
func_dict_loaded[-1]['func1'](x)
```

to return the result of `func_1` for variable `x`.

Thanks to everyone who looked and commented/answered, I hope this can help someone else with a similar problem in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I would expect the functions to be in `func_dict_loaded.items()`, and if you want to call the function `_i7` then you do `func_dict_loaded['_i7']()`.

I've tried to reproduce your problem but avoiding manipulating `globals()`. It's not a safe thing to do. You don't need to do that to make a dict of functions, you can just create your own.

So, in one session:

```
>>> import dill
>>> def myfunc():
        print("Hello world")
>>> mydict = {"myfunc": myfunc}
>>> with open (r"C:\..etc..\Temp\dict.p","wb") as f:
        dill.dump(mydict,f)
```

And in another session:

```
>>> import dill
>>> mydict=dill.load(open (r"C:\..etc..\Temp\dict.p","rb"))
>>> mydict
{'myfunc': <function myfunc at 0x000001FC9F4C69D8>}
>>> mydict["myfunc"]()
Hello world
```

As you can see, reduced to that level of simplicity, it all works.

Comment: Hi @BoarGules , thank you for your suggestion. I have tried `func_dict_loaded.items()`, the values are simply a lot of strings, either of the same keys nested within another key or of filepaths to modules. I can't see any of the items I wanted to include either, such as `func_dict`, `Interp1dPicklable`, `PolyValPicklable` . I think I might have pickled it incorrectly, but I can't see where this could have happened.