# Why cannot I pickle interp1D function but interp2D functions

Tags: python-2.7, interpolation, pickle, instance-methods

I am trying to pickle interpolated functions into binary files. I wonder why it works well with interp2d functions and not with interp1d function.
The error message is: 
PicklingError: Can't pickle type 'instancemethod': it's not found as **builtin**.instancemethod

Is there an easy way to bypass this problem? Have you got some explaination?

Many thanks to those who can help!

Example code:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

X = np.array([1,2,3])
Y = np.array([1,2])
Z1 = np.array([[10,10,10],[20,20,20]])
F1 = interpolate.interp2d(X,Y,Z1)
File = open("F1.bin","wb")
pickle.dump(F1,File,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

X = np.array([1,2,3])
Z2 = np.array([10,10,10])
F2 = interpolate.interp1d(X,Z2)
File = open("F2.bin","wb")
pickle.dump(F2,File,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: I don't get any errors when trying your code. Both F1 and F2 files are successfully pickled. Which Python version are you running?

Comment: I run Python2.7 (but I cannot change the version).

Comment: There are only 3 protocols available to Python 2x [(see docs)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format). It seems the HIGHEST_PROTOCOL you're selecting is Version 2. As I'm not able to reproduce your error running Python 3.x, it sees that pickling of interp1 functions may not be possible

Comment: Also, try the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883491/pickling-scipy-interp1d-spline)

Comment: Ok thank you it works with this class definition!